# Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template calling resource provider actions using POST

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to call POST actions from an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template? I have custom resource provider where I can create resources and call actions using POST as follows:

POST
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CustomResourceProvider/resource/{resourceName}/actionName

Is there a way to call this action from a template?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is none. ARM Templates can only do PUT calls, not POST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question. I try to answer.

> The operations available for each Azure Resource Manager resource
>   provider. These operations can be used in custom roles to provide
>   granular role-based access control (RBAC) to resources in Azure.
>   Refer to: [Azure Resource Manager resource provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations)

It is desgined for RBAC to grant access. It seems can not be used for calling in ARM template.